# The argument type 'Map<String, Object>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'

Tags: flutter, dart, object, key

I am developing basic flutter app. The app was working fine as long as I have changed the list of questions to the key and object pairs of questions and possible answers.....Can someone please guide me how to fix it?
[image: This is the code]

I have tried giving the key of the question but still the error exists.[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code as _text_ rather then an image

Answer (score 1):

I think type cast will solve your problem.

```
questions[_questionIndex] as String
```

or

```
Map<String, String> instead of Map<String, Object>
```

Comment: yes it worked by simply adding "as String"...Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Declare questions like this

`List<Map<String, dynamic>> questions =`

instead of

`var questions =`

Access a question like this

`questions[_questionIndex]['question'] as String`